# Need to frame a mysql query for below scenario

Tags: mysql, sql, join, select

Hi I need to frame a MySQL query for the below scenario

I am having tables like tbl_project, tbl_object1, tbl_object2, tbl_object3, tbl_object4, tbl_item. Here I am having 50 entries in tbl_project.

In that each entries will have unique column object_id which has value 1 or 2 or 3 or 4. If the object_id is 1, then the object details for that project will be in tbl_object1, likewise if the object_id is 2, then the details for that project will be in tbl_object2 and so on.

And in respective object tables(tbl_object1, tbl_object2, tbl_object3, tbl_object4) I am having unique column item_id. And for the unique item_id we have to fetch the item_name, item_details.

So, For all my 50 entries, its respective object data from any of the object tables(tbl_object1, tbl_object2, tbl_object3, tbl_object4) based on the object_id and then item data from tbl_item based on the respective item_id from the respective object tables(tbl_object1 or tbl_object2 or tbl_object3 or tbl_object4).

Could you please help me out

Comment: I can't imagine not having a lot of problems working with that design.

Answer (score -1):

Your first effort should go into fixing your data model. Spreading your data over several tables makes things unnecessary complicated and inefficient - as you are starting to see. These four `tbl_object*` tables should be normalized in just one table.

That said: you can do this with multiple `left join`s:

```
select p.*, i.item_name, i.item_details
from tbl_project p
left join tbl_object1 o1 on p.object_id = 1
left join tbl_object2 o2 on p.object_id = 2
left join tbl_object3 o3 on p.object_id = 3
left join tbl_object4 o4 on p.object_id = 4
left join tbl_item i on i.item_id = coalesce(o1.item_id, o2.item_id, o3.item_id, o4.item_id)
```

If you want to eliminate projects that have no match in the coresponding object table, you can add the following `where` clause:

```
where i.item_id is not null
```

Comment: yes agreed data model is very complex & unnecessary tables were created by someone and suggested to changeas well lets see